# Racket - outputting in numerical form the placement of a string within a list (from left to right)

Tags: recursion, boolean, racket

I've been tasked with creating a function that tells the placement in numerical form of a string within a list (from left to right), so that:

```
(position "a" '("a" "b" "c" "d" "e"))
```

returns 1

```
(position "b" '("a" "b" "c" "d" "e"))
```

returns 2 and

```
(position "z" '("a" "b" "c" "d" "e"))
```

returns #f

I've written it as such:

```
(define (position x L)
  (if (pair? L)
      (if (equal? x (car L))
          1
          (+ 1 (position x (cdr L)))
          )
      #f)
  )
```

Unfortunately,

```
(position "z" '("a" "b" "c" "d" "e"))
```

Doesn't work at all since it's trying to add #f to a number. Is there any way out of this pickle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct, but I'll suggest a different approach: by using a [named `let`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html#%28part._.Named_let%29) for implementing [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) we'll obtain a more efficient solution. Also notice how using [`cond`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._cond%29%29) (instead of nesting `if`s) simplifies things:

```
(define (position x L)
  (let loop ((L L) (acc 1))
    (cond ((null? L) #f)
          ((equal? x (car L)) acc)
          (else (loop (cdr L) (add1 acc))))))
```

Also, in the SRFI-1 library we can find the function [`list-index`](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#list-index) which *almost* returns what you want, we just have to add one to the result to convert it to a 1-based index:

```
(require srfi/1)

(define (position x L)
  (cond ((list-index (curry equal? x) L) => add1)
        (else #f)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by doing:

```
(define (position x L)
  (if (pair? L)
      (if (equal? x (car L))
          1
          (let ((p-cdr-L (position x (cdr L))))
            (if p-cdr-L
                (+ 1 p-cdr-L)
                #f)))
      #f))
```